# Changing Text's text and getting measuredWidth in Flex

Tags: flash, apache-flex

I have a Text element in mxml. The text value is changing by user actions. I want to set the width to the exact size of the text. Since the width property is the actual component's width, I need the measuredWidth property after the FlexEvent.UPDATE_COMPLETE event is triggered:

```
textField.addEventListener(FlexEvent.UPDATE_COMPLETE, function(e:FlexEvent):void{
    textField.width = textfield.measuredWidth;
});
```

This only changes to the proper width the first time. After that it only can be smaller but not larger. I've read the Text and the UIComponent source, and it said I need to call invalidateSize(). But it only works if I set the explicitWidth property NaN. So I made a setter function:

```
function setText(newValue:String):void {
  textField.text = newValue;
  textField.explicitWidth = NaN;
  textField.invalidateSize();
}
```

But it's still only shrinking. My question is, how can I get always the proper measuredWidth value after the UPDATE_COMPLETE event?

Thanks

Comment: Just curious why do you need this property? Maybe you're trying to solve some problem which can be solved other way?

Comment: What I really need is to adopt the Text element size to the content text's size so it's always the same width. Is there a better practice for that?

Comment: Am I right you need your `Text` control to change height to fit all the text?

Comment: The width is what I want. It's always 1 line and I need it to be displayed in one row.

Comment: Constantiner, if you make your comment an answer I can accept it as a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the Text element to Label solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with some of the commenters that there may be better alternatives that achieve the same result. However, you could use the [measureText](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/UIComponent.html#measureText%28%29) function of your Text element to determine the necessary width:

Comment: I know, but as I said, it works if the measuredWidth is a smaller value than before. For me it only set properly at the first set. From then it's not reliable.